# Restricted Access for user via SSH and FTP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps

Hello i have a 14GB RAM VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 on it and i want to rent parts of it for gameservers. My Problem is that i want to restrict Customer1 to the directory `/home/customer1/server/*` and he should only be able to edit a few defined files and should only be able to run a `start.sh` file but cannot edit it also he should not be able to do any other commands other then `./start.sh`.

How would i do it so that the customer can't reboot the VPS or stop it or mess with the system.

Cheers,

Comment: Have you considered chroot, LXC, or Docker containers?

Comment: Im gathering ideas on how to achieve this and which way is the safest and secure one.

Comment: chroot is probably one of the better approaches... though I don't have the actual setup procedures lying around right now...

Comment: If you want limited access users for a shared task (like git) then you can use chroot, file permissions and sudo. But what you're doing is offering shared time and resources. You should use LXC for this.

Comment: Okay I've got it to work but now I don't know how to limit the user to his own server console. Users can start their server with the start.sh which starts a screen session so the server doesn't shut down when the ssh programme gets closed. How would I limit the user to only resume the screen session of his own server? Or is their a different way instead of screen?